# Providing Express Authorization token for RESTFUL API

Tags: node.js, express

Looking at the following express code, how can I create a token to feed Authorization?
If I comment on this code, the application runs fine.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.get('Authorization')

  if (token) {
    req.token = token
    next()
  } else {
    res.status(403).send({
      error: 'Please provide an Authorization header'
    })
  }
})
```

Here is

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'The token I need to generatet' }})
```

Comment: Do you want to generate a token to send to the client ?

Comment: I think I need to generate a token so thant the  instructions on the if {} are true, and the app is using Authorisation. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal approach would be to generate a token on `/login` and send it to client.
Using a package like [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Example method to generate a token:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
function generateToken(userId){
const privateKey = "Some Strong Secret String";
const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, privateKey, function(err, token) {
console.log(token)
});
}
```

To verify if token is valid (inside the if{})

```
jwt.verify(token, privateKey, function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    /*
      err = {
        name: 'TokenExpiredError',
        message: 'jwt expired',
        expiredAt: 1408621000
      }
    */
  }
});
```

Comment: @Shery Gupta where do I call generateToken(), what argument should I pass?  if (token)  is undefined.

Comment: You need to generateToken in your login rest api route  and send the token if login is successful and send the generated token in response . So that client can use that token to make further api calls